# I am getting white screen

Tags: java, android

I am making a weather app but when I run the code I am getting an empty white screen.

Below is my ApiService class where I passed parameters for retrofit.

```
public interface ApiService {
    @GET("/v1/search.json?key=af3b893252df43f8a9e165152182908&q")
     Call<Weather> getWeather(
            @Query("key") String mKey,
            @Query("q") String mCityName);

}
```

Below is the WeatherClient.java class where I have declared url

```
public class WeatherClient {

    private static final String ROOT_URL = "https://api.apixu.com";

    /**
     * Get Retrofit Instance
     */
    private static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Get API Service
     *
     * @return API Service
     */
    public static ApiService getApiService() {
        return getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiService.class);
    }
}
```

I am getting following exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

```
below my Weather.java Pojo class

public class Weather {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("region")
    @Expose
    private String region;
    @SerializedName("country")
    @Expose
    private String country;
    @SerializedName("lat")
    @Expose
    private Double lat;
    @SerializedName("lon")
    @Expose
    private Double lon;
    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    private String url;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getRegion() {
        return region;
    }

    public void setRegion(String region) {
        this.region = region;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public Double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(Double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public Double getLon() {
        return lon;
    }

    public void setLon(Double lon) {
        this.lon = lon;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

}

below my json response

[
    {
        "id": 803267,
        "name": "Paris, Ile-de-France, France",
        "region": "Ile-de-France",
        "country": "France",
        "lat": 48.87,
        "lon": 2.33,
        "url": "paris-ile-de-france-france"
    },
    {
        "id": 790830,
        "name": "Les Batignolles, Ile-de-France, France",
        "region": "Ile-de-France",
        "country": "France",
        "lat": 48.88,
        "lon": 2.32,
        "url": "les-batignolles-ile-de-france-france"
    },
    {
        "id": 760995,
        "name": "Batignolles, Ile-de-France, France",
        "region": "Ile-de-France",
        "country": "France",
        "lat": 48.88,
        "lon": 2.32,
        "url": "batignolles-ile-de-france-france"
    },
    {
        "id": 813415,
        "name": "Saint-Merri, Ile-de-France, France",
        "region": "Ile-de-France",
        "country": "France",
        "lat": 48.85,
        "lon": 2.35,
        "url": "saint-merri-ile-de-france-france"
    },
    {
        "id": 805471,
        "name": "Port De La Villette, Ile-de-France, France",
        "region": "Ile-de-France",
        "country": "France",
        "lat": 48.88,
        "lon": 2.37,
        "url": "port-de-la-villette-ile-de-france-france"
    },
    {
        "id": 761826,
        "name": "Belleville-Villette, Ile-de-France, France",
        "region": "Ile-de-France",
        "country": "France",
        "lat": 48.88,
        "lon": 2.37,
        "url": "belleville-villette-ile-de-france-france"
    },
    {
        "id": 787420,
        "name": "La Villette, Ile-de-France, France",
        "region": "Ile-de-France",
        "country": "France",
        "lat": 48.88,
        "lon": 2.37,
        "url": "la-villette-ile-de-france-france"
    },
    {
        "id": 822578,
        "name": "Villette, Ile-de-France, France",
        "region": "Ile-de-France",
        "country": "France",
        "lat": 48.88,
        "lon": 2.37,
        "url": "villette-ile-de-france-france"
    },
    {
        "id": 778641,
        "name": "Grenelle, Ile-de-France, France",
        "region": "Ile-de-France",
        "country": "France",
        "lat": 48.85,
        "lon": 2.3,
        "url": "grenelle-ile-de-france-france"
    },
    {
        "id": 813697,
        "name": "Saint-Ouen-Sur-Seine, Ile-de-France, France",
        "region": "Ile-de-France",
        "country": "France",
        "lat": 48.9,
        "lon": 2.33,
        "url": "saint-ouen-sur-seine-ile-de-france-france"
    }
]
```

Comment: where do you can `getWeather`? What do u means by `empty white screen`?? Please Provide more information(e.g logcat).

Comment: have you checked your logs to see if any Exceptions were thrown?

Comment: We don't have any crystal balls, so please add more details

Comment: @Shahriar, I am getting white screen when I run on the emulator I have put break point runned debug mode and I am getting following Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=401, message=Unauthorized, url=http://api.apixu.com/v1/search.json?key=af3b893252df43f8a9e165152182908&q&key=key&q=q}

Comment: @Shahriar I am calling getWeather method on MainActivity.java       ApiService api = WeatherClient.getApiService();

        /**
         * Calling JSON
         */
        Call<Weather> call = api.getWeather("key", "q");

Comment: @Stultuske, I have posted logcat please check unauthorized but I called json on postman it is giving corrent response I did not understand where I am making mistake

Comment: Please dont put more information into comments. Instead: add such things to the question (you can edit it!), and delete all these comments.

Comment: can you tell me the sample city so that I can run test it locally

Comment: @Sumat Jha Name of the city is Andijan

Comment: @SumitJha can you see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting Json array for Weather not a Json object. Change the return type in the method.

```
public interface ApiService {
    // You don't need to explicitly pass ``key`` and ``q``. These query params will be added by retrofit automatically.
    @GET("/v1/search.json")
     // return type is List<Weather>
     Call<List<Weather>> getWeather(
            @Query("key") String mKey,
            @Query("q") String mCityName);

}
```

Comment: Also make sure you are using correct api key. As you mentioned in the comment - http 401 is unauthorized. (you should get 200 OK if everything goes fine)